# Passing a variable by value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, reference

I've seen lots of similar questions, but feel like I'm still missing something.  I have the following code:

```
_setHotKeys: function(values, buttons){
    var hotKeyMap = {
            target: document, 
            binding:[]
        }; 

        values.forEach(function(value, index){
            if(value.hotkey){
                this.button = buttons[index]; 
                hotKeyMap.binding.push({
                    key: value.hotkey,
                    fn: function(key, event){
                        this._handleFillInValueButtonToggle(this.button, true); 
                    },
                    scope: this 

                }); 
            }

        }, this)    


        var keyMap = new Ext.util.KeyMap(hotKeyMap); 
},
```

In this function I am trying to set up hotkeys using Ext.js. This code will set up a hotkey for each of the values in the `value` array, but they all set `this.button` to the last button in the `buttons` array. My conclusion is that it is pushing a reference to `this.button` rather than the value into the array, so as the loop progresses, this value changes.  How can I set it to push the value instead of the reference?

Comment: How about `this._handleFillInValueButtonToggle(buttons[index], true)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @elclanrs that worked! for some reason I thought `buttons` would have been out of scope

Comment: @tibsar They are in the same scope, as the function referenced by `fn` and the `buttons` array are both inside the scope of your `_setHotKeys` function.

Comment: @elclanrs ah, that makes sense.  If you post an answer, I'll mark it accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track with that conclusion.

For every iteration of the loop, you've assigned `this.button` to be equal to the button at that index of the loop. If we break this out, it looks like;

```
this.button = buttons[0]
this.button = buttons[1]
this.button = buttons[2]
```

And so on until it reaches the end of the loop. Once it reaches the end of the loop `this.button` is equal to the last button in your array. So naturally when the hotkey event executes, it uses the reference to `this.button`, which points to the last button in your array.

Instead of assigning the reference to the class property, you should pass the button[index] reference to your handler directly.

```
...
fn: function(key, event) {
   this._handleFillInValueButtonToggle(button[index], true);
}
```